# Escape character \t behaves differently with space

Tags: python

Why do I see output only if I put space.

```
print "I love you %s" % "\tI'm tabbled in."
print "I love you %s" % " \tI'm tabbled in."
```

output

```
I love you  I'm tabbled in.
I love you      I'm tabbled in.
```

Answer (score 12):

Typically, \t (TAB) goes to the *next* [tab stop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_stop) - it is *not* a synonym for "n spaces".

```
 I love you XI'm tabbled in.
 I love you  XXXXI'm tabbled in.
 0---1---2---3---4---
```

The current terminal is configured with a tab stop size of 4 which is shown on the bottom. The "X" are the characters skipped by the tab.

So the first line skips *one* character with the tab (it goes to tab stop #3) and the second line writes a space and then skips *four* characters (to get to tab stop #4).

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understand totally. I am new to coding/scripting..Can you elaborate please?

Comment: The point of the tab character is to make strings of uneven length line up properly. Go into something like Notepad, type `hat` on one line and `chat` on the next, then put a tab at the end of each line and notice how the next thing you add to the end of each line will be nicely aligned.